# Easy Rotated Rectangle Collision

Tags: java, awt, collision-detection, java-2d, rectangles

I'm making a game using LibGDX, but I have run into a problem concerning rectangle collision detection.

```
public class Rectangle{
   final float width = 1f;
   final float height = 0.5f;
   Point topLeft;
   Point topRight;
   Point bottomRight;
   Point bottomLeft;  
   //The point of rotation is the middle of the rectangle
   float angle;
}

public class Point{
   float x;
   float y;
}
```

Using this information (all these variables would be pre-calculated), I want to calculate if two rectangles are overlapping at all?

Comment: *"but I am not sure on how to continue with detecting the collision of them, and what I have searched so far has been very complicated."*  And ..what is your question?  Be warned if it is "How to do Easy Rotated Rectangle Collision?" the answer is "hire someone".

Comment: The 'easy' way is probably to check [`Rectangle2D.contains(x,y)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.html#contains%28double,%20double%29) for each of 4 x,y pairs representing the corners of the other rectangle.

Comment: I don't believe that the Rectangle class has a way to angle the rectangle sadly.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Edited my post, hope it clears some stuff up.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, that won't work for [these rectangles](http://imgur.com/WQrMFYV)

Comment: Have a look at the Separating Axis Theorum http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane_separation_theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If two rectangles intersect, there will be a point inside one rectangle that is also inside the other rectangle.

You can consider each rectangle as four lines.  To be inside the rectangle, a point has to be right of the left line, left of the right line, above the bottom line, and below the top line.  So a rectangle can be represented as a system of four linear inequalities which has solutions.

If you combine the four linear inequalities of one rectangle with the four linear inequalities of the other rectangle into an eight-inequality system, the new system will have solutions only if the rectangles intersect.

Comment: This was what I was originally thinking, but I would have thought it would be to long, I'll post the code in a sec.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I ended up using, note that I didn't feel like optimizing the code at all, yet.

```
private boolean isColliding(Point p){
    float countCol = 0f;
    // BottomLeft - BottomRight
    float slope = ((player.getBottomLeft().getY() - player.getBottomRight().getY()) / (player.getBottomLeft().getX() - player.getBottomRight().getX()));
    float intercept = (player.getBottomLeft().getY() - (player.getBottomLeft().getX() * slope));

    // BottomLeft - TopLeft
    float slope2 = ((player.getBottomLeft().getY() - player.getTopLeft().getY()) / (player.getBottomLeft().getX() - player.getTopLeft().getX()));
    float intercept2 = (player.getTopLeft().getY() - (player.getTopLeft().getX() * slope2));

    // TopLeft - TopRight
    float slope3 = ((player.getTopLeft().getY() - player.getTopRight().getY()) / (player.getTopLeft().getX() - player.getTopRight().getX()));
    float intercept3 = (player.getTopRight().getY() - (player.getTopRight().getX() * slope3));

    // TopRight - BottomRight
    float slope4 = ((player.getTopRight().getY() - player.getBottomRight().getY()) / (player.getTopRight().getX() - player.getBottomRight().getX()));
    float intercept4 = (player.getBottomRight().getY() - (player.getBottomRight().getX() * slope4));

    // Between top and bottom
    if(player.getAngle() > -90 && player.getAngle() < 90){
        // BottomLeft - BottomRight
        if(p.getX() * slope + intercept < p.getY()){
            countCol += 1;
        }

        // TopLeft - TopRight
        if(p.getX() * slope3 + intercept3 > p.getY()){
            countCol += 1;
        }
    }
    else{
        // BottomLeft - BottomRight
        if(p.getX() * slope + intercept > p.getY()){
            countCol += 1;
        }

        // TopLeft - TopRight
        if(p.getX() * slope3 + intercept3 < p.getY()){
            countCol += 1;
        }
    }

    // BottomLeft - TopLeft
    if(player.getAngle() < 0){
        if(p.getX() * slope2 + intercept2 > p.getY()){
            countCol += 1;
        }
        if(p.getX() * slope4 + intercept4 < p.getY()){
            countCol += 1;
        }
    }
    else{
        if(p.getX() * slope2 + intercept2 < p.getY()){
            countCol += 1;
        }
        if(p.getX() * slope4 + intercept4 > p.getY()){
            countCol += 1;
        }
    }

    if(countCol >= 4){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```